# How to navigate posting form data to external url in Blazor Server Side?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I'm working on an e-commerce which has to redirect to an external payment gateway while posting form data.
A trivial process in Html5 but I wonder how may we manage this on a blazored way.

```
<form action="https://externalUrl.com" method="post">
  <input type="number" name="amount">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting that html block in Index and clicking the button.

Comment: Yes, sure, this would work; I just thought there should be a way more in line with Blazor EditForm component rather than plain html

Comment: You could construct a Http client post if you wish.  Although `EditForm` appears to have things in common with `form` they are really totally different.

Comment: I want to ask this exact question, but the accepted answer ATM doesn't answer it. It rather talks about server to server communication however question is about browser to external server communication.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I have no more details/circumstances to add. Question already have all the details I want to ask. I understand that exact answer may not be available; but that doesn't mean an irrelevant thing becomes an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `EditForm`. But keep in mind the differences between `EditForm` and HTML's `form` element.

You will need something like:

```
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@inject HttpClient HttpClient
@page "/"

<EditForm Model="postObject" OnInvalidSubmit="PostExternal">

    @*Model Parameter is the top level model and an EditContext will be created from this model. Handy for validation using Data Annotations.*@
    @*OnInvalidSubmit will be executed when the validation on the model succeeds.*@
    @*Custom validation can be done using the EditContext and OnSubmit Parameters*@

    <DataAnnotationsValidator /> @*For validation to work*@
    <ValidationSummary /> @*All validation messages*@
    <InputNumber @bind-Value="postObject.Price" /> @*These default blazor components require to be within the EditForm component*@

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</EditForm>

@code {
    PostObject postObject = new PostObject();

    async Task PostExternal()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync<PostObject>("some.url.com", postObject);

        //Do what you need with the response object
    }

    internal class PostObject
    {
        [Range(0, 9999)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
}
```